Django static url not seem to be loading css file
I'm actually new to Django and tried to load my theme into newly created project.
I have a home.html template file placed at {APP_NAME}/templates/ directory of my Django project. The APP_NAME is called website here and projectname is dentist. Here is the structure top-level directory of project:
dentist
env (virtual environment)
static
    website
        css
            templatemo_style.css
        images
            ...
website
    templates
        home.html
manage.py

As you see the static files are placed in the static under the APP_NAME.
Now here is the home.html:
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>free template one - templatemo</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="{% static 'website/css/templatemo_style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

And this is settings.py added configuration:
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]

But now the problem is whenever I load the project, the css file is not being loaded and the html is corrupted!
I check the source code and it shows this link:
<link href="/static/website/css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

However it is not found and the page comes up this way:



Try putting the entire static folder inside your website app folder, just like you have already done with the templates folder.  Also put home.html inside another folder called website.  So you will have website->templates->website->home.html.

Move your static folder into the website(your app) folder.
Also, create a folder named website (app name) in the templates folder and move home.html there.
This will be your final file structure.
website
  static
    website
      css
        templatemo_style.css
  templates
    website
      home.html

I hope this will solve your issue.

The name of the variable STATICFILES_DIRS has a S you wrote STATICFILES_DIR
